# Netsuite workflow or formula for a field

Tags: netsuite

I need help on how to create the following workflow please.I added a new body field in the Netsuite sand box called “sow.”  It is a check box field and I added it to the sales order transaction page.  Is it possible to make a formula that says:  If “contract type” equals “sow”, check box, if not don’t check box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a single state workflow with two Set Field Value actions: one to Check the snow field if the contact type equals "sow" and the other to uncheck the snow field if contact type different of "snow".

You are obliged to use two actions because an action set only one value for a specific field when one or multiple conditions are true.

So when you have two different cases (val1 OR val2) you need to use two actions.

You can do something like this (**of course you need to set the best Trigger On value for your case**)

[image: uncheck]

[image: check]

[image: summary]

**EDIT**: If the two fields are not on the same, then you must decide on the best event to trigger your workflow and your actions, for example, create a workflow that trigger on the creation of a SO, and set your actions on the before user edit event. And you must configure the actions condition like this:

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. You are awesome. I appreciate your help

Comment: Assem, i was talking to finance and the requirement changed now. The field contract type is on the opportunity now and once this is contract type is set to SOW the checbox SOW on the opportunity should be checked. I tried again the above workflow but it didnot work. Can you help please?Thanks

Comment: Well, I will try to help, but if my answer was good for your initial question, then please mark it as the right answer.

Comment: In your second case, both "contract type" and "sow" fields are on the opportunity?

Comment: for the second case, the contract type field is on the opportunity and sow field is on the sales order. Thanks Assem i appreciate all your help.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you some hints about how to do that, but it is up to you to choose the best events.

Comment: Hi Asem thank you for you rhelp. I am not sure I understand what do u mean so do i put workflow condition for every state. Please can you help me in this. Thanks

Comment: Well, I won't be able to help much: but you must keep in mind that setting your field sow value depends on another record not displayed when manipulating your SO record. I mean, if you are creating the So from an Opportunity, then you can configure your workflow to start at the loadRecordEvent and trigger the setValue action at the before user edit event (of course you need to change your condition to depend on the joined Opportunity record like I did in the picture). This way, when the SO is created, the sow field will get the proper value depending on the contract type of the related Oppor