# NetSuite Workflow

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript

I need help on how to create the following workflow please. I added a new body field in the NetSuite sand box called “sow.” It is a check box field and I added it to the sales order transaction page. Is it possible to make a formula that says: If “contract type” field that exists on opportunity equals “sow”, check box, if not don’t check box? So the field contract type is on the opportunity and once this is contract type is set to SOW the checkbox SOW on the opportunity should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow will need a single State. The State will have a single *Set Field Value* Action, which will mark the checkbox accordingly. This Action will have a Condition that looks at the value of the *Contract Type* field.

Comment: Hi Eric thank you for your reply. I tried it this way but am sorry may be am not clear above. But the Contract type field is on the opportunity and the checkbox SOW is on order transaction page. How can this be done? So once the contract type on opportunity is equal SOW then the field SOW on transaction order should be checked.

Comment: appreciate if anyone can help me with this workflow. I am new b to Netsuite

Comment: appreciate it if anyone can assist me

Answer (score 0):

New Workflow

- Name the Workflow
- Give it an ID
- Record Type: Transaction
- Sub Types: Sales Order
- Trigger Ttype: Before Record Load
- WorkFlow Condition: [Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CrrK.jpg)
- Field: SOW -- Compare Type: checked
  [Workflow Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gItY.png)

Comment: It looks like you asked this question before and it was answered. [Netsuite workflow or formula for a field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092394/netsuite-workflow-or-formula-for-a-field)